# How to setup Cloud9 project with remote files

Tags: cloud9-ide, bluehost

I currently use Kompozer for web development. I can open and save remote files on my bluehost server. I would like to create a project in Cloud9 with the same functionality. I can mount my root bluehost directory as an sftp share. But that is not what I want. I want the files I edit in my project to actually be the files on my bluehost.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, I think what you need is an SSH workspace, not hosted. A Cloud9 SSH workspace is one that would utilize your Bluehost server rather than a container hosted on Cloud9 servers.

Also, please note that you can edit files within an FTP/SFTP mount like you would normal workspace files. There's no need to copy files from the mount, edit and then copy back. FTP/SFTP mounts work like any other folder within Cloud9.

Comment: I just want to be able to use Cloud9 the same way I do Komposer--except that it will be in the cloud, so I can access my workspace from anywhere. Perhaps the only solution would be to see if I can install Cloud9 on my bluehost server. But I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Comment: A Cloud9 SSH account is the same as the hosted account, the only difference being that it uses your machine. You log into Cloud9 and click on the workspace as usual and access it from anywhere

Comment: What is the proper way to use Cloud9 to do continued development on an existing website?

Comment: Is an SSH account a different type of account? Maybe that's the problem--I set up the wrong type of account.

Comment: There are multiple ways. You can use git to deploy, FTP/SFTP, and then there's SSH workspaces that you can edit on the machine (still might have to copy to the proper folder for deploying etc., but changes happen within the machine)

Comment: Well, see, that's what I mean. I don't want to have to work on files and then copy them back to the directory where they live. Like I said -- in Kompozer I open a remote file for editing (using SFTP), and edit it. The changes immediately show up online because I'm editing the actual remote file. I think a lot of development environments work this way. I know Dreamweaver does.

Comment: Its not a type of account, its a kind of workspace. But its only available on the Paid plans. Here's a link to docs: https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/running-your-own-ssh-workspace

Comment: If you want to use SFTP, you can mount it on a normal workspace. I thought you didn't want it. You can edit files within an SFTP mount as normal files.

Comment: Aha! That may be it. I'll see if I can get that working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72900/discussion-between-abalter-and-mutahhir).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that too, and was a long journey trying, testing and findinh solutions...

So i did this small tutorial, hope it helps who need!

It worked for me:

https://github.com/diogowernik/procedimentos/blob/master/connect-c9-bluehost.md

The steps in the link:

1) Connect with your bluehost account via terminal

2) Create ssh folder and insert the data from your c9 account

```
ssh yourusername@yousite.com 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh'
```

3) Go to you file manager, in your cpanel, with show hidden files on find the folder .ssh/

Inside this folder create a file:

```
authorized_keys
```

Paste the ssh number from c9 inside this folder and save

4) download and install node.js in your home directory, via terminal, for example, my home directory is home1/

In my case i had to install node 0.12.9 the new versions were not working with my bluehost account

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v0.12.x/node-v0.12.9.tar.gz

tar -xzf node-v0.12.9.tar.gz

cd node-v0.12.9

./configure --prefix=/home1/yourusername/node/ 
make  
make install
```

5) install python

Enter the following commands to download and extract Python 2.7 to your hosting account.

```
mkdir ~/python

cd ~/python

wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tgz

tar zxfv Python-2.7.2.tgz

find ~/python -type d | xargs chmod 0755

cd Python-2.7.2
```

Install Python

Once extracted you can use the following commands to configure and install Python.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/python

make

make install
```

Modify the .bashrc

For your local version of python to load you will need to add it to the .bashrc file.

```
vim ~/.bashrc
i (insert)
```

click Enter to paste

```
export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.2/:$PATH
```

Write the changes (press ESC) and close vim:

```
:wq
```

Press Enter

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Note: You may need to logout for the environment to update. Enter python -V to check the version of python installed.

6) In your c9 account put the path to your node instalation:

```
user : yourusername (from bluehost)

host name: yoursite.com

path to node: /home1/yourusername/node/bin/node
```

click create

and thats it...